# How to filter lt of time

Tags: vba, excel

I'm wondering how to filter many time variables.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$G$18").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("11:45:00 AM", "11:46:00 AM", "11:47:00 AM", "11:48:00 AM", "11:49:00 AM" _
, "11:50:00 AM", "11:51:00 AM", "11:52:00 AM", "11:53:00 AM", "11:54:00 AM", "11:55:00 AM", "11:56:00 AM", "11:57:00 AM", "11:58:00 AM", "11:59:00 AM", _
"12:00:00 PM", "12:01:00 PM", "12:02:00 PM", "12:03:00 PM", "12:04:00 PM", "12:05:00 PM"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

this is how I have been filtering time but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it. like asking the user in a box to type the start time and the end time and it will automatically filter the time.

[image: how the data looks]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVNz2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is from a recorded macro, modified to fit yours

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$F$4:$G$18").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=11:45:00 AM", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=12:05:00 PM"
```

Comment: wow thank you so much for the answer and that is a lot simpler, but its not selecting the numbers between 11:45-12:05. so nothing on the excel sheet is showing up how do i select it?

Comment: what do you mean when you say  "not selecting the numbers between 11:45-12:05" ?  do you mean "not selecting anything" ?

Comment: yea it filters from 11:45-12:05 but they arent selected in the filter box (checked in the box) so no data shows up.

Comment: do you see a checkmark next to "number filters" in the filter control box?  go to that

Comment: were you talking about the little checkboxes in the filter control box?

Comment: yea that check box, I eddited in a picture so u can see what I mean sorry for the bad wording.

Comment: you have an option for "text filters" where mine shows "number filters". i think that your "Time" column is formatted as _text_. try formatting the column as _time_